# How to enable mouse tracking on a QLabel that has RichText

Tags: python, pyqt5, qlabel, qmouseevent

I really want a single QLabel to have different colours for different parts of the string. Past questions have led me to the solution of using HTML4 rich text options within it, for example:

`'<font color="red">I\'m red! </font><font color="blue">I\'m blue!</font>'`

This solution works great visually when passed into `QLabel.setText()`, but for some reason I'm finding that mouse tracking completely breaks within the widget once it uses rich text.

Here's the MRE, with a normal QLabel and empty background space as a control:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QLabel
from PyQt5.QtGui import QMouseEvent
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QEvent
import sys


class testWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(testWindow, self).__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle('QLabel Test')
        self.setMouseTracking(True)
        self.resize(600, 200)

        # label that displays coordinates picked up from mouseMoveEvent
        self.coordLabel = QLabel(self)
        self.coordLabel.setText('Mouse at:')
        self.coordLabel.setStyleSheet('''QLabel {background-color:#088;}''')
        self.coordLabel.setGeometry(0, 0, 200, 200)
        self.coordLabel.setMouseTracking(True)

        # label with multiple colours for different sections of the string
        self.richTextLabel = QLabel(self)
        self.richTextLabel.setText('<font color="red">I\'m red! </font><font color="blue">I\'m blue!</font>')
        self.richTextLabel.setStyleSheet('''QLabel {background-color:#880;}''')
        self.richTextLabel.setTextFormat(Qt.RichText)  # text format is explicitly set to RichText
        self.richTextLabel.setGeometry(400, 0, 200, 200)
        self.richTextLabel.setMouseTracking(True)

        # everything has mouse tracking set to True
        # 3 blocks: coordinate label, empty space, rich text label
        self.show()

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event: QMouseEvent) -> None:
        if event.type() == QEvent.MouseMove:
            x, y = event.x(), event.y()  # coordinates of mouse
            self.coordLabel.setText('Mouse at: {}, {}'.format(x, y))  # set to coordLabel text


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = testWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

What I'm looking for is either a way to fix the mouse tracking on these QLabels. Although if there's another way to make a QLabel with multiple colours in one string of text that would be helpful too.

Thanks :)

Comment: Is your problem that when hovering the label you're not getting mouse move events?

Comment: Yes! As you can see in the MRE, no mouse move event is detected and thus no coordinates are passed into the coordLabel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, Qt widgets (anything that, directly or not, inherits from QWidget) do not **accept** mouse events.

Whenever an event is not accepted by a Qt object (aka, a [QObject](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html)), it is automatically sent to its parent, up in the [object tree hierarchy](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/objecttrees.html). As soon as an object in that hierarchy accepts the event, it's not propagated anymore.

Consider that:

- by default, events are normally accepted (see [the documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qevent.html#accepted-prop));
- if the event was already accepted and isn't explicitly *ignored* (or wasn't previously ignored), the parent will not receive it;
- an event *could* be handled by an object (because it reacts to it) but it could still be set as ignored, because it's important that the parent receives it;

Whenever a QLabel has rich text content (either automatically detected or explicitly set using `setTextFormat(Qt.RichText)`), mouse events are automatically accepted anyway, and that's because they're normally handled; most importantly, because rich text can often include *anchors* (hyperlinks).

If you need to get any event received by a child widget, the *only* safe way to do so is by installing an event filter on it.

Now, the problem is that mouse events sent to a widget use *local* coordinates, so if you want to get absolute coordinates relative to the parent, you have to *map* them (see the `map*()` functions in the QWidget documentation).

This is a possible implementation that considers the above:

```py
class testWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        ...
        self.richTextLabel.installEventFilter(self)

    def updateCoordLabel(self, pos, obj=None):
        if isinstance(obj, QWidget) and obj != self:
            if not self.isAncestorOf(obj):
                return
            pos = obj.mapTo(self, pos)
        self.coordLabel.setText('Mouse at: {}, {}'.format(pos.x(), pos.y()))  # set to coordLabel text

    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        if obj == self.richTextLabel and event.type() == event.MouseMove:
            self.updateCoordLabel(event.pos(), obj)
        return super().eventFilter(obj, event)

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event: QMouseEvent) -> None:
        if event.type() == QEvent.MouseMove:
            self.updateCoordLabel(event.pos())
```

Note that avoiding layout managers is almost always a bad idea, unless you **really** know what you're doing. Layout management considers a lot of important aspects; the most important are the system font, OS font scaling, and screen DPI (including High DPI) settings; those aspects then result in changing the requirements, aspect, and, most importantly, **usability** of each widget. Ignoring all these aspects will almost always result in having a UI that for some reason becomes completely unusable:

- widgets could overlap, resulting in:

  - making them partially invisible (because they've been hidden by others);
  - not usable, because mouse events are captured by widgets stacked above them (even if it doesn't look like they are) which will get mouse events intended for the underlying widget;
- contents could be clipped due to the forced geometry; this is specifically the case of QLabel: if the user uses a big font size or has huge font scaling set (for instance, because they have some visual impairment), the text will be only partially visible, if not completely hidden;
- the screen might not be big enough to show all contents, hiding some widgets;

You may not care for the above aspects, but you must remember that what you see on your screen is almost ***NEVER*** what anybody else will see, which in some cases is a *completely* different look than the one you expected.
Ignoring those aspects will make your program unusable for some people, and for the wrong reasons.

If you do that because you want more control on the way the layout is managed, then it's the *wrong* reason. Just learn how to deal with layout managers: which means understanding what [`sizeHint()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#sizeHint-prop) is and how it's used, the purpose of [size policies](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsizepolicy.html), [generic layout management](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html) (including spacing and stretch factors) and the purpose of [layout items](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlayoutitem.html).

Comment: Thanks! So to clarify, this was happening because rich text labels default to their own special event handling because of the possibility of hyperlinks? Or am I misunderstanding that?

Comment: @mazelover1939 Yes, the main cause of the problem was that. Qt always tries to send mouse events to the topmost (active) widget that is under the mouse, if, after that, the event is *not* accepted, it will then sent to the parent of the widget, and so on until some widget (if any) accepts it. That's why you cannot rely on simple overrides of event handling functions on parent widgets, as there's a high probability that the event will never be received by them. Note that the event filter could even just set the event as ignored and `return True` (without doing anything else); in your simple ->

Comment: -> case, it would have been actually received by the `mouseMoveEvent()` override, but just because there are no "intermediate relatives" between the label and the window (parents of the label that are children of the window) that actually accept the event. If any intermediate parent accepted it you wouldn't have received the event in any case, even if the label hadn't any formatting. That's why it's almost always necessary to install event filters when you need to intercept events from another object: not only it's *reliable*, but it's also more accurate in the object structure.